# ReactJS how to refer to an object using another variable

Tags: reactjs

I have a variable containing a string.  This string is itself the name of another object.

say

```
const myObject = {"some": "Object in JSON format"};

const myObjectName = 'myObject';
```

How can I use the string contained in the variable 'myObjectName' to call a function manipulating myObject?

Comment: You can't touch a variable name using a string as far as I know

Comment: Seriously?  It's possible the function doesn't exist but doesn't that make the language non Turing complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const myObject = {"some": "Object in JSON format"};
const myObjectName = 'myObject';
function myFunction (obj) {
   console.log(obj);
}

eval(`myFunction(${myObjectName})`);
```

[This works but eval is dangerous and should be avoided](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)